# JAXB/JAXWS, Generics And Inheritance

Tags: generics, inheritance, jaxb, xsd, jax-ws

I am creating a SOAP WebService when I use following classes:

First, I have an abstract and generic class:

```
@XmlTransient
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class PaginatatedListContainer<T> {
@XmlElement
protected List<T> elements;

    ...getter and setter
}
```

Then, I have two classes which inherits passing a type as class parameter

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CollaboratorPaginatedList extends PaginatedListContainer<Collaborator> {
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GenericUserPaginatedList extends PaginatedListContainer<GenericUser> {
}
```

My problem is when I use wsimport to generate the client of my WS, the generated CollaboratorPaginatedList and GenericUserPaginatedList do not have their own list with the proper type.
I verified in the WSDL/XSD and I see there is an object list instead and I don't understand why.

Can you help me understand, please? And is there a way to force JAXB to type the list?

Thank you :)

PS: I tried [@XmlElementWrapper with a generic List and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911444/xmlelementwrapper-with-a-generic-list-and-inheritance)

============ My answer because I am new and I can't answer my own question :)

I found a workaround but to me, it is not very clean.
First, I saw this link in the related section

[Creating abstract generic jaxb class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244652/creating-abstract-generic-jaxb-class?rq=1)

The parent abstract class:

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class PaginatatedListContainer<T> {

    public abstract List<T> getElements();
    public abstract void setElements(List<T> elements);

}
```

The children classes:

```
@XmlType
public class CollaboratorPaginatedList extends PaginatedListContainer<Collaborator> {

    @XmlElement
    private List<Collaborator> collaborators;

... reimplemented getter/setter
}

@XmlType
public class GenericUserPaginatedList extends PaginatedListContainer<GenericUser> {

    @XmlElement
    private List<GenericUser> collaborators;

... reimplemented getter/setter
}
```

In fact, in the XSD/WSDL, I have what I want because of the @XmlElement on the typed lists and not because of the abstract getter/setter.